# What did Maggie mean?

Tags: october-faction

When Maggie was talking to Edith, the head of Prosidio, about what information she could offer, she said that she could provide information on a "hybrid". At first I assumed that she was talking about Geoff and Viv, but upon further thought, since

> both their parents were warlocks

that wouldn't seem like a very accurate description.

Another possibility is that she means Dante, assuming she even knew about him. But again, hybrid doesn't seem like quite the right word to describe what had been done to him, since he's just an ordinary human who was subject to some summoning ritual.

So what does she mean?